# Need guidance about multithreading application in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

If there is any multithreaded c# utility is there, i have bit poor knowledge about this concept. but what if following situation encounters?
Out of running 1000 of thread ,If one or more threads get failed during its execution ,then what is the plan to recover this or is there any way to restart it from its current state when i get failed ?

Comment: it **depends** on your situation? How your threading is implemented etc... You need to be way more **specific** for this question to be answerable!

Comment: you should use the `ThreadPool` class or equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty unclear, but a here few thoughts:

- It generally is a very bad idea to spawn 1000 threads in terms of memory consumption and application performance. Instead consider to use `ThreadPool` or Task Parallel Library.
- If an exception is thrown in one thread and the thread does not handle the exception your application will crash. If you want to centrally manage such situation you can attach to the event `Application.ThreadException` to handle the situation by e.g. showing some kind of sorry-message to the user before closing your application.

Comment: i am sure it encounter exception in catch block. but how can i continue thread from its current state, also while resolving other threads should not get affects. what is the remedy... so is that means in catch block i need to call thread by its identity,current state? if yes how can we store its current state?

Comment: Well, this really depends on the situation. If the exception is not critical, you might catch and swallow it. But exceptions should not be used to control program flow. Nevertheless, this question is closed, so to get senseful answers you should create a new, more specific question.